# Add text disclaimer with button property in .dialog() from jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Actually I wanted to add a text disclaimer in-front of "Agree" button which is generated from jQuery UI. Below is the code, so how can I add text (Are you sure want to ?) before the button. Any help appreciated.

```
   $(DialogAuth).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: $(RevalidationButton).attr("RevalidationTitle"),
    height: 250,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Agree": function () {
            Authenticate(this, RevalidationButton, true, Revalidate);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```js
   $(DialogAuth).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: $(RevalidationButton).attr("RevalidationTitle"),
    height: 250,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "text" : "button text here",
        }    
});
```

Comment: It sets the button text(change the display text of button). I am looking to Add  a text besides the button @Meraj Khan

Comment: `$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").append("text");`  add this.